# Nativescript Angular 2 - How do I pass variables in tap function (xml)?

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I have a listview of user posts. I want to implement a like function. I want to pass the post id to the function, so I can add the like to the database.

Pressing the Stacklayout should trigger the like function.

home.component.html (crashes)

```
<ListView [items]="posts">
    <ng-template let-post="item">
        <StackLayout (tap)="likePost( {{ post.id }} )>
            ...
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListView [items]="posts">
    <ng-template let-post="item">
        <StackLayout (tap)="likePost(post.id)>
            ...
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

In your home.component.ts

```
likePost(id) {
//Use Id here and register the line
}
```